# PNotify on jQuery Mobile - Problems with the style

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, pnotify

My problem is that the content on the page appears above the notification. I tried playing with `.ui-notify`'s z-index, but that didn't change anything.

Also, the notification is always white, even if I specify `type: "error"` or `type: "success"`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/newblt123/3vcL7/1/)

Am I missing something? Thanks!

## UPDATE

I achieved to get the look and feel of PNotify (with Bootstrap) notifications with the following css (requires FontAwesome). See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/newblt123/3bFLH/4/)**.

```
/* info */
.ui-pnotify-container{
    color: #31708f !important;
    background-color: #d9edf7 !important; 
    border-color: #bce8f1;
    background: none;
}

/* error */
.ui-pnotify-container.ui-state-error {
    color: #a94442 !important;
    background-color: #f2dede !important; 
    border-color: #ebccd1;
    background: none;
}

/* success */
.ui-state-default {
    color: #3c763d !important;
    background-color: #dff0d8 !important; 
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
    background: none;
}

/* warning */
.ui-pnotify-container.ui-state-highlight {
    color: #8a6d3b !important;
    background-color: #fcf8e3 !important; 
    border-color: #faebcc;
    background: none;
}

.ui-pnotify-container .ui-icon {
    background: none;
}

.ui-icon-close{
    position: relative;
    text-indent: 0px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.ui-icon-close:before {
    content: "\f00d";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;           
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a z-index issue, rather your background color on the notifications is transparent for some reason. There is something wrong with your CSS or the order it is loading in...

> Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3vcL7/2/)**

By adding these CSS rules to your fiddle, the notifications are no longer transparent:

```
.custom-notif {
    background: white;
}
.ui-state-error {
    background: red;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.ui-state-default {
    background: green;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.ui-state-highlight {
    background: blue;
    text-shadow: none;    
}
```

Comment: I now realize that the problem is that (I think) PNotify has never been meant for/adapted to jQuery Mobile. In order for it to work properly, I need to include a jQuery UI theme (which I don't really want to do since I already got a jQuery Mobile theme). The other solution is, as you've shown, to add manually the missing styles. Please correct me if I am wrong in any way.

Comment: @AntoineCloutier, I dont't use pnotify, but it looks from their site that you use jQueryUI or Bootstrap to style the notifications. It is probably not the best choice for jQM. For very simple growl like notifications, I have used alertify with jQM before (http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/). There are of course many others to choose from...